# How to change the default recipient address while scheduling a report in business objects?

Tags: business-objects

i am working with 
SAP BusinessObjects
WEB INTELLIGENCE XI
Version:12.5.0
Build:1190. In my scenario i want to send my report to many receipients. But i dont know where to edit the default recipient settings. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way to add the recipient and sender manually. the default recipient option need to be unchecked and then we need to provide the sender mail id and receiver mail id and we need to add the file with extension.
For eg.
Sender: xyz@stackoverflow.com
Recipient: zyx@stackoverflow.com
sub: anwer
file: answer.xls

we need to add the extension along with the file name to receive the file as excel or else it will receive as desktop intelligence file.

Answer (score 0):

From **InfoView** you can set the recipients for a particular scheduling run.  Click on the "Formats and Destinations" tab, select the format and destination (Inbox, File location, FTP, or Email), then click on "Destinations Options and Settings" to choose the recipients.

To set the *default* recipients (or any other scheduling options), you must use the CMC.  It the report's Properties, there is a **Default Settings** tab.  Set your default scheduling settings here (this action will not actually create a schedule).  Now, when you schedule the report (either from CMC or InfoView), it will reflect the default settings you have chosen.  Note that what you set for default settings will apply to **anyone** who schedules the report, not just you.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out.

Comment: Even we can change the Recipient and sender without going to CMC. We need to uncheck the default sender option and provide the sender, receiver, subject of the mail and the file . So that we can send to any recipient without changing the default recipients

Comment: I understood your question to mean that you wanted to change the default scheduling settings, not that you wanted to override the defaults for a particular schedule.